# Create an instance of a bookable product object in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-bookings

With WooCommerce I am using WooCommerce Bookings plugin. I need to get a bookable product object with the product ID. Unfortunately. When using:

```
wc_get_product( intval( $post_id ) );
```

It always returns false. I thought, passing in product id can return me an object.

Do I need to include anything or it this to be called inside any hook?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: its exist..all data is there

Comment: maybe, I found, wordpress functions are not working in this file

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, bookable product..its using woocomerce booking plugin

Comment: I have quickly set a bookable product on a test server. the Id of this product is `741`… When I use `$product = wc_get_product( 741);` and `var_dump($product);` I get the an instance of the `WC_Product_Booking Object` … So there is something that you are doing wrong.